# Issues with displaying label value for h:commandButton

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have an issue with displaying the label value for the `<h:commandButton>`. For example, please see the below code

```
<td align="left"  style="float: left;">
            <h:commandButton value ="Reset Demand To Default"  styleClass="refresh-button-style" />
        </td>
```

I have created the styleclass for this button and the code for the styleclass is specified below.

```
.refresh-button-style
{
word-wrap: break-word !important;
background-color:#2996EF;
height:40px;
width:100px;
font-size:13px;
text-align: center;
font-family: Arial;
 }
```

When I try to run the xhtml file and disable the label value, The label value seems to get displayed horizontally. It does do the wordwrap and hence displays only part of the button label. Can you please let me know how to achieve the wordwrap for the button and display the entire label value within the command Button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following css attribute:

```
white-space:normal;
```

This should wrap the text as expected ([source](http://daipratt.co.uk/wrap-text-on-an-button-with-css/)).

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt, It did work. But for one of the buttons, the entire label value is not getting displayed. part of the labelvalue is getting missed/deleted.

Comment: Do you see only parts of the label or no label at all? Are there any other css styles involved with that label? If the label is dynamically generated, try to use a static value for testing.

Comment: Hi Matt, I tested by adding a static value for testing. Still the same issue. Im trying to add value="Reset Demand To Default" and In the commandbutton, only Reset Demand To is coming as the label value. Not sure why? Can you please suggest what I need to do to display the entire value on the button. Im using the same style class as above. Instead of word wrap, replaced with White-space.

Comment: Try to find the difference between the working one and the not working one with Firebug or other dev tools. Check which styles are applied. Try to swap both buttons...